# How to run the Powershell File which Located in remoted Server using rundeck

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, rundeck

I Need to Execute the Power shell file which located in the remote Machine using rundeck.

So far I have done this:

1. Create a Node with the server **AS123**
2. Created a New Job Under the Projects.
3. In the Job Workflow I have chosen Add a Step -> **Script file or URL** and did the below Setup.

[image]

This setup is searching for the Powershell file path in the rundeck server rather than the remote host server **AS123**.

Can anyone share the steps How to call the powershell which is hosted in remote Server and Execute the same on the remote host.

Comment: If I got you right you should use the UNC path of the file on the remote server.

Comment: @Olaf - I tried it but didn't worked. Got the Same Error that the path not exists.         [AS123: FileNotStreamableError: /data/Deploy/git/rundeck/\\AS123\test\fun-Test.ps1 (No such file or directory)]}, Node failures: {AS123=[FileNotStreamableError: /data/Deploy/git/rundeck/\\AS123\test\fun-Test.ps1 (No such file or directory)]}, status: failed]

Answer (score 1):

use one of the following instead.
Personally I prefer using the inline script cause it more flexible.

[image]

use the exact command line you use when running the script locally on your server via cygwin (I presume).
i.e

```
powershell.exe 'd:\scripts\test\fun-test.ps1' -path Testing
```

Make sure to select dispatch to nodes and filter your relevant server.

[image]

When using 'script file or URL' it should be a path rundeck can access cause it runs locally on the rundeck server.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. When I Use the Command to run the Powershell I Ended up with Power shell winRM Password double Hopping Issue.

Comment: To my understanding this issue will happen no matter how you run it as it's described as "security feature" and not a bug. I would try inline script cause it enables you to set extra params before running the script. It might be useful for you. Is it working properly when you run it locally on the server?